# I need to connect to a single IP using multiple telnet sessions, is there a way to do it? Below is my code in python

Tags: python

This is one session of telnet, I want such multiple sessions to be connected.

```
import telnetlib
import time

tn = telnetlib.Telnet("10.13.135.3",23)
time.sleep(10)
tn.write("/H")
print tn.read_until("Enter Password:")
tn.write("power" + "\r\n")
time.sleep(5)
print tn.read_eager()
tn.read_until("IPS>")
tn.write("/OFF 1" +"\r\n")
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: so connect multiple times. `tn1 = ...; tn2 = ....; tn3 = ...`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple ... you can make additional connection like this.

```
tn1 = telnetlib.Telnet(...)
tn2 = telnetlib.Telnet(...)
```

and then you can work with them as usuall

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to create multiple simultaneous sessions. I will recommend either threading or multiprocessing. Here is an example using multiprocessing (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

```
import multiprocessing
import telnetlib
import time

def connect():
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet("10.13.135.3",23)
    time.sleep(10)
    tn.write("/H")
    print tn.read_until("Enter Password:")
    tn.write("power" + "\r\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    print tn.read_eager()
    tn.read_until("IPS>")
    tn.write("/OFF 1" +"\r\n")
    time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_connections = 5 # This should be an arg (--num_connections)
    processes = []
    for i in range(num_connections)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=connect, args=())
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```